# Why mixed Folder with files after disabling New Folder

Tags: 2010, document-library, folder

I created a document library in SharePoint 2010 and created many files and folders. In the default view (All Documents) the folders display first, followed by files (just as Windows Explorer does).

Then I disabled "new folder" command in library properties by setting **Make "New Folder" command available? = No**. After that folders are now mixed with files in all views for this document library.

I tested it on various libraries and it always shows this strange behavior. How do I make folders always displays before files?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the display order in the View settings.  Sort first on Content Type (Z to A) then on Title (A to Z).  Sorting on content type z to a will force the Folder content types to be listed at the top and the documents to be listed below them getting the back to what you were seeing previously.

Comment: This solution is not suitable, because when you open this view and select a different sort order, for example, by modified date files and folders will again mixed. And if command "New Folder" is active, the folders are always displayed before files

Answer (score 0):

If you are still experiencing trouble with this question I would like to clarify why you may be experiencing following the previous answer:

It sounds like you may have tried to sort based on "file name" content type as opposed to the content type which actually defines whether the entry is a file or a folder.

In many cases this content type could be defined as "type". Now if you follow the directions of the previous answer using the "type" content type you should experience your desired result of ordering the folders ahead of documents in your list.

Think of it as an order reset that you must do after disabling folders. hope this helps if the issue has not yet been resolved.